# Flutter Usage of Drawer with Routing and check the current active route to hight light in drawer?

Tags: flutter

Need example with Flutter drawer using routes with current route to be highlighted in menu and also return to homepage route  from any other route, app exit from homepage only

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I have came up with:

```
import 'package:myapp/blocs/provider.dart';
import 'package:myapp/routes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerItemList extends StatelessWidget {
  String getCurrentRouteName(context) {
    String currentRouteName;

    Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
      currentRouteName = route.settings.name;
      return true;
    });

    return currentRouteName;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
    String currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName(context);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text('MyAppTitle'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              tooltip: 'Log Out',
              onPressed: () {
                bloc.logOut();
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                  context,
                  AppRoutes.home,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
          selected: currentRoute == AppRoutes.home,
          onTap: () {
            if (currentRoute == AppRoutes.home) return;

            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
              context,
              AppRoutes.home,
            );
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.list),
          title: Text('Records'),
          selected: currentRoute == AppRoutes.records,
          onTap: () {
            if (currentRoute == AppRoutes.records) return;

            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
              context,
              AppRoutes.records,
            );
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Planning'),
          leading: Icon(Icons.graphic_eq),
          selected: currentRoute == AppRoutes.planning,
          onTap: () {
            if (currentRoute == AppRoutes.planning) return;

            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
              context,
              AppRoutes.planning,
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```